# When is hashcode useful if I am never using hashtable?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Lets say I am implementing a class called Car, with 2 member variables int numDoors, and String color.

In a hypothetical case, I am never going to use such a car in hashtable or hashmap or any structure that needs a hash, time immemorial.

Now, why is it still required to override hashCode along with equals ?

Note: all answers I checkout include use in hashtable / hashmap. I have tried extensively to get this answer, so as a request dont mark it as a duplicate. Thanks

Comment: you don't have to if you are **sure** that no body is ever going to use this class's object in hash based data structure (which isn't generally a case)

Comment: I might put a car in a Map (because I need to store it in a Session). So your hypothetical case seems spurious. Also, you might want them to be `Comparable` unless you never intend to sort `Cars`. And you might want to Override `toString()` because it makes it easier to log things.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you `have to` override hashCode?
Are you implementing some interface, if so is hashCode a part of that interface. If it is then you need to implement it.

Comment: You are correct.  If you are certain that instances of your class will never be used as keys in a HashMap or Hashtable or HashSet, you don't need a hashCode method.  But if you intend for your class to be at all reusable, you should expect that someone, somewhere, will try to use it in a hash-based collection.  HashSets are used more commonly than Maps.  It's not hard to imagine that you, or someone else, might want a Set of Cars in their application.

Comment: First it's a contract (convention) of Object, and yes it's main use case is HashMap/HashTable... but you can add HashSet, IdentityHashMap to your list. Other libraries like ORM will also use this assumption for their implementation details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's the general convention:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

> If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

However, it's not entirely enforceable.

There are times in which you would *believe* that you don't need to have `hashCode` defined and implemented for your object, and if you don't use any structure that relies on a hash to store or reference it, you'd be correct.

But, there are third-party libraries in which your object may come into contact with, and they may very well be using a `Map` or `Set` to do their work, and they'd have the expectation that you followed conventions.

It's up to you to not implement `hashCode` along with `equals` - you're certainly not forced to (although many would argue that this is a bug), but beware that your object may not work as well with a third party library for this reason.

Comment: This is a politically-correct version of my answer. :) +1 BTW

Comment: Is there any legitimate reason why an object which overrides `equals` and can't define anything else useful for `hashCode()` to return should let it return the `identityHashCode()` value rather than returning a constant [which would lead to correct behavior, even if not to very efficient behavior]

Comment: I can't think of any instance in which an object that overrides `equals` would have nothing meaningful/useful to provide for `hashCode`.  I would imagine that (and I would hope that the general convention is) for one to take the `hashCode` of the fields involved with overriding `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

The only conceivable types which would not be able to override `hashCode` method in a fashion consistent with the `hashCode` and `equals` contract would be those which are unable to override `hashCode` [e.g. because a base class declared it `final`].  There is thus almost never any reason for a type not to legitimately implement `hashCode()`.  Even if a type cannot guarantee that instances which are unequal won't spontaneously become equal, the author of the type may still legitimately implement `hashCode()` by picking a 32-big `int` value [e.g. 8675309] and implementing `hashCode()` as `@override int hashCode() { return 8675309; }`.  Doing this will allow all of the hash-table-based collection types to work correctly.  Storing very many such items into a hash table will severely degrade performance, but hash tables with just a few items will work just fine and generally perform decently.  By contrast, if one doesn't override `hashCode` then even a hash table will likely work incorrectly if even a *single item* is stored into it.

Incidentally, in some cases there may be advantages to implementing `hashCode` even when not using hashed collections.  For example, some immutable collection types which support deep comparison might call `hashCode()` on the items stored therein.  If a collection is large, and/or comparison operations on the items stored within it are expensive, the efficiency of testing two collections for equality ("do they contain equal items") may be enhanced by using a three-step process:

1. Compare the aggregate hashcode of two collections.  If they're not equal, no reason to look any further.  Will often yield instant results, no matter the size of the collections.
2. Compare the cached hash codes of all the items.  If the collections' contents match except for the last couple items, and if comparisons between items may be expensive (e.g. the items are thousand-character strings) this will often avoid the need to compare all but one of the items for equality [note that if all but one of the items matched, and its hash code differed, then the aggregate hash code would differ and we wouldn't have gotten this far].
3. If all the hash codes match, then call `equals` on each pair of items that don't compare reference-equal.

Note that if two collections contain distinct items with equal content, a comparison is going to need to deeply examine all of the items; `hashCode` can't do anything to help with that case.  On the other hand, in most cases where things are compared they are not equal, and using cached `hashCode()` values may facilitate orders-of-magnitude speedups in those cases.